# No resources found error after deploying Django app

Tags: django, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my app to Heroku using this tutorial:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django#deploy-to-heroku

I managed to push my app to Heroku, but I keep getting this error when I try to make sure I have at least one dyno running:

```
(tapeworm_django)Christophers-MacBook-Pro-2:tapeworm christopherspears$ heroku ps:scale web=1
Scaling dynos... failed
 !    No app specified.
 !    Run this command from an app folder or specify which app to use with --app APP.

(tapeworm_django)Christophers-MacBook-Pro-2:tapeworm christopherspears$ heroku ps:scale web=1 --app tapeworm
Scaling dynos... failed
 !    Resource not found
```

I ran the command inside the same directory as my Procfile:

```
/Users/christopherspears/PyDevel/tapeworm_django
(tapeworm_django)Christophers-MacBook-Pro-2:tapeworm_django christopherspears$ ls *
README.md         requirements.txt

tapeworm:
Procfile   drawings/  manage.py* tapeworm/  templates/
```

Any hints?

UPDATE:

I can get it to run locally:

```
(tapeworm_django)Christophers-MacBook-Pro-2:tapeworm christopherspears$ foreman start
16:43:17 web.1  | started with pid 2366
16:43:17 web.1  | 2014-03-29 16:43:17 [2366] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 18.0
16:43:17 web.1  | 2014-03-29 16:43:17 [2366] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (2366)
16:43:17 web.1  | 2014-03-29 16:43:17 [2366] [INFO] Using worker: sync
16:43:17 web.1  | 2014-03-29 16:43:17 [2369] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2369
```

Comment: Are you sure the app is getting pushed correctly? Is `git remote -v` pointing to the correct repo?

Comment: Seems to be point at the right repos:  `heroku git@heroku.com:tapeworm.git (fetch)
heroku git@heroku.com:tapeworm.git (push)
origin https://github.com/cspears2002/tapeworm.git (fetch)
origin https://github.com/cspears2002/tapeworm.git (push)`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this to work.  First, I moved my Procfile up a level, so my project is structured like so:

```
tapeworm_django/
  Procfile
  README.md
  requirements.txt
  tapeworm/
    drawings/ <- app
    manage.py
    tapeworm/ <- project configuration folder
    templates/
```

I moved the Procfile up a level because I see that most developers seem to place the file in the root directory.  Am I wrong?

Then I changed the contents of the file to from

```
web: gunicorn tapeworm.wsgi
```

to

```
web: python tapeworm/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT --noreload
```

I am unsure if that solution is considered "proper" because it seems to clash with the Getting Started With Django tutorial:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django